# R Bates authentication with authorize in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am rolling R Bates authentication from scratch from [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised), and I'm wanting to put the call to the authorize method in the application controller. Basically I want the entire app locked down. Here is the app controller...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authorize
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def authorize
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not authorized" if current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

But the probably is I'm getting an infinite loop in my URL call. How should I hand this?

## sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip `before_filter` (like in @vee answer) for some actions of `SessionsController`:

```
skip_before_filter :authorize, only: [:new, :create]
```

Alternatively you can modify `authorize` method to avoid redirects in some cases:

```
def authorize
  return if skip_authorization?("#{controller_name}##{action_name}")
  redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not authorized" if current_user.nil?
end

def skip_authorization?(location)
  %w(sessions#new sessions#create).include?(location)
end
```

Comment: Yep, you're right @Lumbee, not the prettiest. I just edited answer mentioning the `skip_before_filter` approach as well.

Comment: Yeah @markets, but the skip filter did not work for me.

Comment: Did you try adding `only: [:new, :create]`? In your pastie I see the redirect when you call the `create` action.

Comment: OK, got ya. Works OK. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

The loop is because of the `redirect_to login_url...`.

You should skip the `authorize` filter in controller that has the `login` action defined as:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController 
  skip_before_filter :authorize, only: :login

  def login
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Or to skip `authorize` filter for all actions, use `skip_before_filter :authenticate` without the `only` option.

Comment: Hmm, no worky. I added the sessions controller above. After adding the skip filter the login page renders, but still can't login, I'm still redirected to the same login page

Comment: @Lumbee, Does the user get authenticated?

Comment: This works also. Just change method name to match question. Thanx!

Comment: @Lumbee, I just saw your suggested edit.  Thanks for the correction.